# Cox proportional hazard model ran out of iterations = summary gave significant results with very small p values

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am running a cox proportional hazard model on a data set of 63 instances and 11 variables. When I do univariate analysis, all runs fine and I get non-significant results for all variables
When I run the same model in multivariate model, it utilizes only 27 instances due to missing values in some variables. It gives me the warning:
"Ran out of iterations and did not converge"
But if I still get summary of the model, almost all variables are significant with very very small p values and abnormally low or high hazard ratios

When I do itermax to increase number of iterations then I get following warning:
"Loglik converged before variable  1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10 ; coefficient may be infinite."
Now when I generate summary, p values are all close to or siply 1.00 and hazard ratios are again abnormally low or high

I am quite new to survival analysis, and could not find a starightforward answer online so would really approciate if I can get an answer from someone

Comment: As you are new to survival analysis, you might not know that it's the number of _events_ that primarily matters, not the number of cases. To avoid overfitting, typically you need about 15 events per coefficient that you want to fit. As Peter Flom says in an answer, you might deal with missing data via [multiple imputation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/). For the too many variables problem, consult Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/), for example Section 4.7 on data reduction, or use a penalized method like ridge regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a prime case of overfitting leading to odd results. You have far too few cases; even without the missing data, it's too many variables. With the missing data - well, it's very sparse.

A partial solution is to do multiple imputation prior to the analysis.

You should also try to figure out if the missingness is missing completely at random, missing at random, or nonignorable.